# Is it possible to server side render when using a useRef hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to find a way to server side render a component within NextJS. I've got an existing component, which I can make small tweaks too, but can't completely re-architect. I'd like to know if there is a way to force a server side render, or some creative approaches to be able to achieve this.

A simplified version of my problem is this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const layer = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        d3.select(layer.current)
          .selectAll("circle")
          ...
    });

    return <svg ref={layer} />
}
```

Due to the fact that I'm using a `useEffect`, this I believe is going to force NextJS to client side render this (which for my larger use case I can't do). I can't think of a way to eliminate the `useEffect` when using a `ref`, however because in this case `React` doesn't own the DOM (`D3` does) I can't think of any other way to achieve this.

Does anyone know of an approach I could use?

Comment: Based on the documentation there is no way to do server components while using hooks. Is d3 even available and provided when compiling the server components? The only way I thought that might work if d3 is available is writing a timer (interval) which checks if the component is mounted if so use vanilla js to get the dom element and do what you need with d3 instead of a ref. Does D3 allow id targeting?  Either way this is not a good approach and you shouldn't manipulate the dom outside of react.

Comment: @floor yeah, that sort of thing might work - and if fairness I asked for creative hacks but I agree it's probably not a good approach to take for robustness. Thanks though!